# When click input, button which is fixed on bottom appears over keyboar in react native android

Tags: react-native, expo

*In ios it is ok however when i click input in android, button appears over keyboard and it seems so bad. how can i handle that ? this is my code:*

```
 <>
  <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
  
    <ScrollView
      contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
      keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
      style={styles.scrollviewStyle}
    >
      <FormInput label="1" />
      <FormInput label="2" />
      <FormInput label="3" />
      <FormInput label="4" />
      <FormInput label="5" icon={true} />

      <Text
        style={{
          color: '#938E8E',
          marginLeft: 30,
          fontSize: 14,
          fontWeight: '400',
        }}
      >
        text
      </Text>
      <Dropdown />

      <View style={styles.agreementContainer}>
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}
        >
          <CheckBox onPress={chekboxButton} checked={toggleCheckBox} />
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={styles.acceptagreementStyle}>
             text
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>

    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
      <Button buttonText="1" onSubmit={() => console.log('test')} />
    </View>
  </SafeAreaView>
</>
```

*this button comes over keyboard:*

```
  <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
      <Button buttonText="1" onSubmit={() => console.log('test')} />
    </View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you can easily fix this problem using
`<KeyboardAvoidingView>` https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview
and wrapping your component with that.

Comment: it doesnt wor. if u add one more button here: </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      <View style={styles.btnContainer}>
            <Button title="Submit" onPress={() => null} />
          </View>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>  , when click input, submit button appear over keyboard

Comment: Did you set the behavior of the KeyboardAvoidView? And is it wrapping ALL your component? Even then <SafeAreaView>, and btw you dont need <></>. If it still doesnt work, check the styles of btnContainer

Answer (score 0):

this is because [android:windowSoftInputMode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#wsoft) property in AndroidManifest.xml which is set to `adjustResize` by default

**you have 2 solutions**

1 : change your `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity
        ....
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

2 : use [react-native-android-keyboard-adjust](https://github.com/zubricky/react-native-android-keyboard-adjust)

```
import AndroidKeyboardAdjust from 'react-native-android-keyboard-adjust';
.....
AndroidKeyboardAdjust.setAdjustPan();
```

Comment: i use expo is this work ? sorry i forget to add expo to tag

Comment: You shouldnt change the Android Manifest directly nor installing external libraries to solve this, not necessary at all.